# Why doesn't the second class name get filled when I tell it to?

Tags: c++

When I call the function to fill the second class, it just passes it somehow.  It is not the call function (fill()) that has an error because I wrote that after I was having this problem.  The code is posted below:

```
class Name_pairs {
public:
    void read_names();
    void read_ages();
    void sort();
    vector<string> names() const { return name; }
    vector<double> ages() const { return age; }
private:
    vector<string> name;
    vector<double> age;
};

void Name_pairs::read_names() {
    string s;
    while(cin>>s) {
        if(s == "|")
            break;
        name.push_back(s);
    }
}

void Name_pairs::read_ages() {
    double d;
      while(cin>>d) {
        if(d < 0)
            break;
        age.push_back(d);
    }
}


void Name_pairs::sort() {
    vector<string> dup_name = name;
    vector<double> dup_age = age;
    std::sort(name.begin(), name.end());
    double buffer;

    for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {

        for(int ii = 0; ii < dup_name.size(); ii++) { 

            if(name[i] == dup_name[ii]) {

                buffer = age[i];
                age[i] = dup_age[ii];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

void fill(Name_pairs& np)
{
    np.read_names();
    np.read_ages();
    np.sort();
}

int main() try
{
    Name_pairs test;
    Name_pairs test1;

    fill(test);

    fill(test1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it 'just passes somehow'?

Comment: You need to post your code here if you want help. If all of the content of your question is located elsewhere, it's useless to future readers trying to search if that link is not available. It also means people have to leave StackOverflow in order to even see what your question is asking. Please [edit] your question to include the **relevant** portions of the code here. Thanks.

Comment: @ Mike Vine: It just fills 'Name_pairs test' class ID and exits.  My full version has it print each one out, so that is how I can tell.

Comment: @ Ken White: Thank you for the tip, I'll remember that for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Name_pairs::read_ages()` method reads from `cin` until the stream is closed.  When you call `fill` the first time, it reads until the stream is closed.  When you call `fill` for your second `Name_pairs` instance, `cin` has already been closed, so nothing is able to be read, leaving your vectors empty for `test1`.

Comment: This sounds right, except the problem is with Name_pairs::read_names() first, then Name_pairs::read_ages().  How can I keep it open for all Name_pairs::read_names() and Name_pairs::read_ages() calls?

Comment: Your escape from the while loop in `Name_pairs::read_names()` is to look for a special delimiter (|).  You would need to create a similar escape in your `Name_pairs::read_ages()` method to signal that it needs to stop reading ages.  Currently, the only way to break your read_ages while loop is to close the stream.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  I changed the void Name_pair::read_ages() function body to stop reading at a negative number.  It is changed in the initial question so anyone else can see it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem would be to call

```
if(!cin) cin.clear()
```

to set the istream state back to good.